# Hbse : How to do the row key filter with two different criteria

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In an Hbase table, the row key is like below:

(particular id)_(date with timestamp)

I want to filter the entries in the table with two scenarios:

a. With a particular id - This can be done by ROWPREFIXFILTER

b. All the rows that falls between two dates. Need to compare with the date in the rowkey(after the "_"). I am not sure how this can be achieved.

So the point is I need to have filters to the row key before and after "_".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an AND or an OR? I mean are you trying to filter records between two dates for an entity or all records of an entity + records of all entities between given dates

Answer (score 0):

It is just an alternative approach, check if it works.

if you have another lookup table with below mapping (Rowkey -> value),

(date with timestamp)_(particular id) ->  (particular id)_(date with timestamp)

a. Use main table for ID lookup

b. for date look up, first get the value / values from lookup table, and use these values to hit main table.